# Alternative for visitor pattern in TypeScript (avoiding instanceof conditionals)

Tags: javascript, typescript

Let's assume I have an interface

```
interface I <T extends InternalResult> {
    doStuff(): T;
}
```

and two concrete classes implementing this interface:

```
class A implements I <InternalAResult> {
    doStuff(): InternalAResult {
        // implementation
    }
}

class B implements I <InternalBResult> {
    doStuff(): InternalBResult {
        // implementation
    }
}
```

My client cannot execute `doStuff()` directly, but needs an instance of a class implementing an `Executer` interface, like one of those:

```
interface Executer <T, R> {
     execute(it: T): R;
}

class AExecuter implements Executer <A, AResult> {
    execute(it: A): AResult {
        let internalResult = it.doStuff();
        // ... do something specific with internalResult create result
        return result;
    }
}

class BExecuter implements Executer <B, BResult> {
    execute(it: B): BResult {
        let internalResult = it.doStuff();
        // ... do something other specific with internalResult create result
        return result;
    }
}
```

For such cases I always used the *Visitor* pattern in Java. I could create a visitor, pass two `Executer` instances to it and implement the `visit` method with an `A` and a `B` overloading, creating a conditional-free solution, like this:

```
class Visitor {
    private aExecuter: AExecuter;
    private bExecuter: BExecuter;

    visit(it: A): Result {
        return this.aExecuter.execute(it);
    }

    visit(it: B): Result {
        return this.bExecuter.execute(it);
    }
}
```

Now, there is no such thing as method overloading in TypeScript / JavaScript. But what is the alternative to creating a conditional like this?:

```
if (it instanceof A)
    aExecuter.execute(it);
else if (it instanceof B)
    bExecuter.execute(it);
```

**Note:** I want to have the `A` class know nothing about `AExecuter`. This would increase the coupling between those two classes and I could not switch the implementation of `AExecutor` easily.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the approach the typescript [compiler team](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/81814057e854873497ee7ffa584d728535e41fb2/src/compiler/visitor.ts#L207) used and have a field that discriminates against the type of field, replacing `instanceof` with a simple string/number comparison, which is probably less expensive (although you should test for your use case):

```
enum Types {
    A, B
}
interface I <T extends InternalResult> {
    readonly type : Types;
    doStuff(): T;
}
class A implements I <AResult> {
    readonly type =  Types.A
    doStuff(): AResult {
        return new AResult();
    }
}

class B implements I <BResult> {
    readonly type =  Types.B
    doStuff(): BResult {
        return new BResult();
    }
}
class Visitor {
    private aExecuter: AExecuter = new AExecuter();
    private bExecuter: BExecuter = new BExecuter();

    visit(it: A | B): AResult | BResult {
        // Since we don't have a default return, we will get a compiler error if we forget a case
        switch(it.type){
            case Types.A : return this.aExecuter.execute(it); break;
            case Types.B : return this.bExecuter.execute(it); break;
        }
    }
}
```

Another approach which requires less writing (but is less type safe) is to use the constructor name as a key for access the correct method:

```
class Visitor {
    private aExecuter: AExecuter;
    private bExecuter: BExecuter;

    visit(it: A | B): AResult | BResult {
        let visitor: (it: A | B) => AResult | BResult = (this as any)['visit' + it.constructor.name];
        if(visitor == null) {
            throw "Visitor not found"
        }
        return visitor.call(this, it)
    }
    visitA(it: A): AResult {
        return this.aExecuter.execute(it);
    }

    visitB(it: B): BResult {
        return this.bExecuter.execute(it);
    }
}
```

Comment: Any reason for the down-vote ? I'm always looking to improve my answer, if there is something factually or fundamentally wrong with it let me know, whoever you are :)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe link the executor directly to the class, like:

```
A.prototype.Executor = ExecutorA;
B.prototype.Executor = ExecutorB;
```

So then you can just do

```
(new it.Executor).execute(it)
```

---

Alternatively one could use a Map to link the class and the Executor:

```
const executors: Map<I, Executor> = new Map();
executors.set(A, ExecutorA).set(B, ExecutorB);
```

which can be used as:

```
(new executors.get( it.constructor )).execute(it)
```

Comment: that would work of course, but I want to have A know nothing about the AExecuter class. otherwise I would create a tight coupling

Comment: @ggradnig then symbols maybe?

Answer (score 1):

You can always skip the visitor pattern completely and use a multimethod library instead, then you can simplify your code to something like this:

```
import { multi, method, Multi } from '@arrows/multimethod'

interface IExecute extends Multi {
  (it: A): AResult
  (it: B): BResult
}

const execute: IExecute = multi(
  method(A, (it: A) => it.doStuff()),
  method(B, (it: B) => it.doStuff()),
)

// Usage:
execute(new A())
execute(new B())
```

It less type-safe (compiler won't warn you if you put a multimethod together incorrectly - but it's trivial code), but it is a much simpler solution.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about the accepted answer but how I managed to circumvent `ìnstanceof` was by adding methods to the base class (alternatively you can just use helper functions) and additional type property.

Eg

```js
class A {
  constructor() {
    this.type = 'A'
  }
  isInstanceOfA(): this is A {
    return this.type === 'A'
  }
  isInstanceOfB(): this is B {
    return this.type === 'B'
  }
}

class B extends A {
  constructor() {
    super()
    this.type = 'B'
  }
}
```

Works like a charm. When compiling the code the type definitions are dropped therefore removing any circular dependencies you have between A and B. However, I found out that after fixing this I found new errors so yey but d'oh also.

Answer (score 0):

One can imporve on accepted answer by using overload call signature

```
class Visitor {
    private aExecuter: AExecuter = new AExecuter();
    private bExecuter: BExecuter = new BExecuter();

    visit(it: A ): AResult;
    visit(it: B ): BResult;
    visit(it: A|B):any {
        // Since we don't have a default return, we will get a compiler error if we forget a case
       switch(it.type){
           case Types.A: return this.aExecuter.execute(it);
           case Types.B: return this.bExecuter.execute(it);
       }
    }
}
```

This way the client whould be able to continue type-safe execution using instance of AResult in case of A and BResult in case of B respectively.

```
const a = new A();
const visitor = new Visitor();

const ra = visitor.visit(a);//const ra: AResult


const b = new B();
const rb = visitor.visit(b);//const rb: BResult
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=62&ssc=1&pln=69&pc=48#code/MYGwhgzhAECCBKBTCBXEAXA3gXwLAChRIYAhJVDHAgSwDt1EAnAMzGEWgEl6nawRyaLHnx0GLNhwCiAD0TAU46AB4AKgBpo8AHzRMBaIcOI5ChgApq6AFzRVASlvwA3AREEiUOLPmKm0agBbAAcQREDEehgfM39lWE0EZCFdfXwjaBNfCytbWEc4QQw9AwyjMPQAnkY+AWTigF4A9AA6ABMAewBldBRmZnN7V3SywwB6MegW6ehO6AgOiPQACzoAc3ng+WpmamBoAHcrZarxWqLK4EZEMAZoa4p0UtHr3prT3n4L6EhC+vRhhkRO5COAvCQYn5GAEQmEIlFoJClMoSJoyP9Us9MqY-JYbNASAV0Y8SiNRhUPjUvv9oE0rO1ur1+oNAaNoBMpjM5gslqtaBsOit-BAtsAdntDsdKecaVcbncHkIsRlXih3mJPnUSb9iUJWYZgR4OrQIJVIihAnYAJ5bGBpDIJAluGjVVjsLgqVTYhi0NowbhnamPTFk+43Tq0EBW6DoG0cWyqOMQfWzRl9AYFVTDESeGCwGGhcKRdD+lRJYOklXh41RmNx2mGRO2lqwLGdHrpwZ5b72tmq960RAHP6PFlYw34Dxg0gFuHF0soi4hqtgCO12NbBvW5skNtp5lEnvKoz92jQQfD3UYMehicEe+g4jQABq1AgVg60N7hmCjGoADdbg4MAkSYPJQOhJoL28HFxBvDJfwAoDoAAIwg2wIVg-woKHAkIJvLF-zfKw8TyaACnLPVCOI9BSIJciMIuFMiPfWjcjgAAfQlrDAWho2-MoOS6Oh3QODgIwAckqZYwH-YDZkQVghDDN5aE0MTJRAEBoDWRBKjAaBgEWYJqDCaEmEYT8AmYQ4OGYT9dP0wzIEQY95iOdBgGWPEWg3RB7AEtlgBc7dkBbWxTxjVYIBaECsMYFosliPEhjcjJgogDgmzCkgIr0tUzxWN8WjQ+LEqwlKUyMEQgWdSd6qMk0nJw4dYBvRrTWgFiP0g89cNfVjPwIwhjU6xgDKabr0E-FopvMMAhgmDrKnG7t-gfI0mtQhtoJIdrRpWlCGymma5pQxaxmW+4UMY-4gA)